# resizing image on carrierwave/mini-magick occuerd unknown format error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i want to resize image file to same size.

using gem

```
gem 'fog-aws'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'carrierwave'
```

and below create model code

```
def design_create
  @design = Design.new(design_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @design.save
      params[:design_attachments]['portfolio'].each do |a|
        @design_attachment = @design.design_attachments.create!(:portfolio => a, :design_id => @design.id)
      end
      format.html { redirect_to action: "design_show", id: @design.id, notice: 'Design was successfully created.' }
    end
  end
end
```

and add uploader.rb below code

```
version :medium_avatar do
  # returns a 50x50 image
  process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
end
```

I coded the above and there was

> ActionController::UnknowFormat  in `respond_to do |format|`

error.

add my console showed

> rollback transaction
>
> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

but if i remove code in uploader.rb before i add.

application Operated well.

how to fix it?

Comment: The error you're seeing has nothing to do with the image resizing, you're getting the error because the browser is submitting using an unrecognized type.  I'd recommend asking a new question including the controller action you've shown here, and your routes.rb for that endpoint, and the full log of the request (so from the `Started` line down to the `Completed` line)

Comment: @smathy thanks for your comment, as a result i solved it. just download imagemagick...((sudo yum install imagemagick))

Comment: Hey man, well done!